# How to make sure that a process was killed? (using kill command)

Tags: linux, process, kill

I try to kill a process with the kill command in linux. (not using -9 as argument)

I need to make sure that the process is really killed.
As far as I know, the kill command runs asynchronously and it can take some time till it is finished.

I need to make sure, after I run the kill that my process has died using bash

Can you please assist?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `$PID` holds the pid of your process, you could do something like this:

```
kill "$PID"

while [ $(kill -0 "$PID") ]; do
  sleep 1
done

echo "Process is killed"
```

Answer (score 4):

Killing a process with signal 0 will check if the process is still running, and not actually kill it. Just check the return code.

Answer (score 0):

`kill` is used to send signals to processes. It doesn't necessarily terminate the process (but usually do). `kill` without explicitly mentioned signal will send `SIGTERM` to the process. The default action on `SIGTERM` is to terminate process but process can setup a different signal handler and process might not be terminated.

What, I think you need, is a way to find if the process has handled the signal or not. This can be done using `ps s $PID`. If this shows `0`s as pending mask, the process has received the signal and processed it.